# colgroup is not working on html5

Tags: html, html-table

i try to give width to the each column of the table using colgroup but it does not effect.the sample code is here

```
<table>
    <colgroup width="100%">
       <col style="width: 5%; background-color: red">
       <col style="width: 15%;">
       <col style="width: 25%;">
       <col style="width: 20%;">
       <col style="width: 10%;">
       <col style="width: 15%;">
       <col style="width: 10%;">
    </colgroup>
    <tr>    
        <th> no </th>
        <th>Reference No</th>
        <th>Vendor Name</th>
        <th>Vendor Name</th>
        <th>Vendor Name</th>
        <th>Vendor Name</th>
        <th>Vendor Name</th>    
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_colgroup.asp

> Most of the attributes [in col group] in HTML 4.01 are not supported in HTML5.

This includes the width attribute.

Comment: Whilst not quite an 'alternative' you could create a set of CSS classes and then apply those to each `<th>` element. That should handle the width in all subsequent rows, but if you want `background-color` as well then I think you will also have to add the CSS class to each `<td>` as well